# Is it safe to use these variables within the doInBackground() method of an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I have a method that looks something like this:

```
public void doSomething(final int num1, final int num2, final String str) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            reallyComplexStatisticFunction(num1 + num2, str);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

(I've greatly simplified the example.)

Is is wise to directly use the parameters supplied to `doSomething()` within the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method? Or will this cause thread-related issues?

Also, would it make any difference if the third parameter was a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) instance instead of a `String`?

Comment: You are just passing/using the values. e.g. you are not passing `num1` but the value in it, which could 1, or 2, or any `int`. It could have made sense to worry if you were passing reference to some mutable object.

Comment: Everything in Java is passed by value.  Therefore, the arguments to doSomething are unqiue to that instance.  If you call doSomething from another thread, it's stack frame will contain another set of copies.  Even the String objects are passed by value - specifically, a copy of the value of the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some guarantees that `AsyncTask` make, which you can see in it's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), but these are mostly regarding access to `AsyncTask`'s fields.

In your example you're using primitives and String. Neither can really be modified so you're safe on that end.

However, if you're using an object that can be modified from another thread then you can't really be sure that it won't be modified between the moment you call `execute()` and when you actually use the object, that it won't be changed right as you read it inside `doInBackground()`, or worse that it will be modified as you try to modify it inside `doInBackground()` and possibly end in a corrupted state. For those cases you'll need to use synchronization to make sure that only one thread can read or modify such object at a time.

If you need to keep the object's value/state as it was when you called `execute()` by the time you use it in `doInBackground()` you might want to clone it and use this clone as a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, as long as you are only passing primitives and/or references to [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Otherwise, you need to make sure that no other thread will be modifying the state of those objects (or synchronize the access to it).

As `String`s are immutable in Java, your example looks fine.